# cannot make live snapshots on ubuntu 12.04 xcp-xapi

Tags: 12.04, virtualization, openstack

I have installed xcp-xapi on ubuntu 12.04, I can run VMs perfectly but I cannot make live snapshots, I receive the following error message:

## xe vm-snapshot new-name-label=my_snap vm=482c0f4c-fa7d-67c1-a178-559b81b79ede

Error code: SR_BACKEND_FAILURE_82
Error parameters: , Failed to snapshot VDI [opterr=failed to pause VDI XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX],

Answer (score 0):

you should check the capabilities of your SR:  do

> xe sr-param-list uuid=[replaceme]

Check

> allowed-operations (SRO): forget; VDI.create; VDI.snapshot; plug;
>   update; destroy; VDI.destroy; scan; VDI.clone; VDI.resize; unplug

Especially for VDI.snapshot, that's what you need, if your SR doesn't have it, it probably means you are not on an LVM backend and/or the xcp-xapi drivers are missing.  I bet you have deployed using 'ext' backend.

Post it here.